# Display amount in format $1,560.00 and $ 50.00

Tags: jsf

I have two fields in screen that need to display the amounts in format like this

```
Amount : $1,560.00
Tax    : $   10.00
```

In my code i am using

```
<h:outputText value="#{mBean.amount}" >
   <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency" 
      maxFractionDigits ="2" />
 </h:outputText>
```

And the output is

```
Amount : $1560.00
Tax    : $10.00
```

How to right align the amount and comma (,) for these amount fields?

Comment: By default it uses the locale of the browser, so by explicitly setting a locale, you can force it in the direction you want. Or try usig the pattern

Comment: You might need to use some CSS or something to do the right-alignment or use the standard DecimalFormat patterns. For the grouping, just set `groupingUsed="true"` on the `convertNumber`

Comment: @Kukeltje *By default it uses the locale of the browser* and I thought it always uses the default locale from the server, not from the client.

Comment: @Luiggi: when `<f:view locale>` is not specified, it indeed defaults to client locale as specified in HTTP request `Accept` header (as long as it's listed in `<locale-config>` of `faces-config.xml`). Only timezone of date converters defaults to server specified one (perhaps this is where the confusion comes from).

Comment: I can right align the currency values, but how to give the appropriate spaces between $ and amount based on other field values. That is for field 1 if the amount is thousand and for field 2 amount is ten dollars. How to give spaces for field 2. Is it possible ?

Comment: For amounts 100000 and 1000 , I used this format in java   DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.00"); and output is $100,000.00 and $1,000.00 , for second amount i want some spaces after $ i.e it should align like this $  1,000.00. So it should align correctly with the first amount. Can any one suggest whether any format can resolve this.